# query " ALTER TABLE test_posts ADD sticky boolean NOT NULL default = false" = error

Tags: sql, mysql, alter-table

Whats wrong with my query?

```
 ALTER TABLE test_posts ADD sticky boolean NOT NULL default = false
```

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=false' at line 2

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to remove the `=`:

```
ALTER TABLE test_posts ADD sticky boolean NOT NULL default false
```

Answer (score -3):

This SQL command should work:

```
ALTER TABLE test_posts ADD sticky bit NOT NULL default 'false'
```

Comment: BIT - key word is boolean data type and give the value in single quotes ('false')

Comment: Can you add the explanation from the comment to the answer?